# Get IList<> detail again filtered

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Hi I get the data in products from below query but i again want products to get filtered and store that data in another Ilist name product1. I had written below code but it snot working, can any bodyu help me out?

```
IList<Product> products = ProductDataSource.FindProducts();//store data in list of products

IList<Product> products1 = products.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Visibility == 2));
```

It will be good enough if Ilist product get filtered and the filtered detail remain in itself only.
So that there will be no need to declare one more Ilist as product1

Comment: There are way too many unknowns (for us) in your code sample. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also, "it snot working" is *never* a good description.

Comment: @PeterB updated the question, now it looks fine?

Comment: Better, now I could focus and formulate an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq method `SingleOrDefault` does not produce a List, it produces a single item (or null).

So it should be:

```
Product product = products.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Visibility == 2);
```

Or if you *do* need a List:

```
IList<Product> products1 = products.Where(s => s.Visibility == 2).ToList();
```

Comment: As i m new in this i don't know Actually I need list of detail having column visibilty=2

Comment: In case if don't want to get detail in products1 and i want by data to get autofiltered in product itself than is it possible?

Comment: If by that you mean changing the value of `products`: that is what variables are for, you can assign and re-assign them as often as needed. So no problem doing `products = products.Where(s => ....`, as long as the type of the new assigned value is the same as the type of the variable (and in this case it is).